# APFS undeclared deleted space and underallocation error

Tags: macos

1. Deleting files does not free any space on the drive.
2. Running Disk Util shows an error: Underallocation Detected on Main device: (37344474+1) bitmap address (730508)

Is there a workaround?

I know this is documented, bugs filed, and many are recommending not to use APFS at this time. It's a little too late for me though. I made the big mistake and upgraded my production machine to 10.13 with APFS. I really can't afford to format back to HFS+ and start over. It would take days, this is my main machine.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but some errors are probably harder to repair when you're booted from the same APFS volume or even APFS container as the volume you're trying to repair. Did you try booting from your local recovery partition (Cmd-R) or Internet Recovery (Cmd-Opt-R), or better yet, an external drive (must be running macOS 10.13 or later to support APFS) in order to try repairing the drive while it's not in use? Even booting single user mode (Cmd-S) and following the on-screen instructions for fsck'ing the disk while it's still mounted read-only, might help.